# Topic on relativistic celestial mechanics

Tags: orbital-motion, relativity, celestial-mechanics

I have to do a small 10-15 minutes presentation about celestial mechanics, and I am searching for a topic.

As a mathematician my background in physics is not very extensive, but I have some notions on relativity and I would love if I could apply them here. Although in terms of orbit determination the relativistic effects do a little role and the error is negligible, so I don't know if it is worth it to go that way.

Is there any topic merging relativity and celestial mechanics that has relevance?

Comment: Looking for advice and ideas is *too broad* a question. Please try to ask specific questions that can have clear-cut, objective answers.

Comment: Maybe this way it is more clear.

Comment: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html may help spark something for you.

Comment: Obviously the precession of Mercury. Or are you interested only in SR?